# Jquery plugin not allowing me to insert Bootstrap badge inside <a> tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've followed the html example of a jQuery sliding menu from the following website:

http://github.danielcardoso.net/sliding-menu/

I'm able to add icons inside the `<a>` tags, however I would also like to insert a bootstrap Badge element inside as well. Currently the jQuery plugin used seems to simply ignore or hide the Bootstrap badge element completely. Is there a way to add a badge element inside the `<a>` tag?

```
<div id="menuHTML">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Catalogue</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bathroom
                        <i class="sm-set-icon fa fa-play"></i> Play
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bedroom</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Kitchen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Living Room</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Orders</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pending</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Completed</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using **font-awesome icons** so i think you are missing the  font-awesome reference link 
add the below link inside your head it will work fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

also see the below code snippet i added Badges ,font-awesome icons and glyphicon for your help. you can Use whatever   you like

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="menuHTML">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Catalogue</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bathroom  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"> </span></a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bedroom   <span class="badge">42</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Kitchen <i class="sm-set-icon fa fa-play"></i> Play</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Living Room</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Orders</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pending</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Completed</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```